# show that $\tan \alpha_i = -t_i$ for each $i=1,2,3$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, conic-sections

> My question pertains to the question and solution below. In particular, can someone prove why $\tan \alpha_i = -t_i$ for each $i$? I think it would be worth clarifying what the angle each normal makes with the axis of the parabola (the x-axis) is. I think it's the smaller of the two angles formed by the normal lines and the axis.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If a line makes an angle $\alpha$ with the positive $x$-axis (measured anticlockwise from the axis), then the line has slope $\tan \alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you have already been able to understand how the normal equation at $(at^2, 2at)$ is derived, then you understand that $y=(–t)x + at^3 + 2at$ has slope “-t”.

Also, by “angles which these three normals make with the axis”, the reference is *not* to the smaller of the angles, but only the angle between the normal and the *positive* direction of the x-axis. That is why tanα = slope, otherwise we would have tan($\pi — α$) = slope for lines making obtuse angles with +X, because slope is defined as the tangent of the angle between the normal and the *positive* direction of the x-axis, measured anti-clockwise with the +X axis as the reference line.